# How to use the Tensorflow Dataset API to read files with different names without evaluating the filename string

Tags: python, tensorflow, file-io

Say I received csv dataset files with filenames of the form `index_channel.csv` where `index` is the index of the example (running from 1 to 10000) and `channel` is the index of the channel (running from 1 to 5). So `7_3.csv` is the 3rd channel of the 7th example. I want to load all these csv files and concatenate the channels to get the correct tensors as my data set. I am missing references to functions which will enable me to do this. Below is the code I have so far. When I get to running it, it complains that `TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not Tensor`. I am guessing it is trying to evaluate the expression instead of only after `sess.run()` has been called, but not sure how to circumvent that.

```
from __future__ import absolute_import
from __future__ import division
from __future__ import print_function

# Imports
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.contrib.data import Dataset, Iterator

def main(unused_argv):
  train_imgs = tf.constant(["1","2","3"]) #just trying the 3 first examples
  tr_data = Dataset.from_tensor_slices((train_imgs))
  tr_data = tr_data.map(input_parser)

  # create TensorFlow Iterator object
  iterator = Iterator.from_structure(tr_data.output_types,
                                   tr_data.output_shapes)
  next_element = iterator.get_next()
  training_init_op = iterator.make_initializer(tr_data)
  with tf.Session() as sess:

    # initialize the iterator on the training data
    sess.run(training_init_op)
    # get each element of the training dataset until the end is reached
    while True:
        try:
            elem = sess.run(next_element)
            print(elem)
        except tf.errors.OutOfRangeError:
            print("End of training dataset.")
            break

def input_parser(index):
  dic={}
  for d in range(1,6):
    a=np.loadtxt(open("./data_for_tf/" + index +"_M"+str(d)+".csv", "rb"), delimiter=",", skiprows=1)
    dic[d]=tf.convert_to_tensor(a, dtype=tf.float32)
  metric=np.stack((dic[1],dic[2],dic[3])) 
  return metric
```

Sorry, I am a newbie at TF. My question seems trivial but none of the examples I found by googling answered my questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks to me like the error is being generated by the use of `index` in:

```
a=np.loadtxt(open("./data_for_tf/" + index +"_M"+str(d)+".csv", "rb"), delimiter=",", skiprows=1)
```

As you suspect, when TensorFlow sets up its declarative model, your input_parser is called exactly once- this sets up the relationship between TensorFlow operations for later evaluation.  Your *Python* calls, however (e.g. numpy operations), are run immediately during this initialization.  It's at this point, `np.loadtxt` is trying build a string using a not-yet-specified TF op.

If fact, you don't need to even run the model to generate an error (try removing `sess.run()`).

You'll notice in the example from https://www.tensorflow.org/programmers_guide/datasets#preprocessing_data_with_datasetmap, that they read in data using TF file access functions:

```
filenames = ["/var/data/file1.txt", "/var/data/file2.txt"]

dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(filenames)

# Use `Dataset.flat_map()` to transform each file as a separate nested dataset,
# and then concatenate their contents sequentially into a single "flat" dataset.
# * Skip the first line (header row).
# * Filter out lines beginning with "#" (comments).

dataset = dataset.flat_map(
    lambda filename: (
        tf.data.TextLineDataset(filename)
        .skip(1)
        .filter(lambda line: tf.not_equal(tf.substr(line, 0, 1), "#"))))
```

which is designed to be part of the declaritive TF model (i.e. to have the filename resolve at runtime).

Here are more some more examples of using TensorFlow ops for reading files:

https://www.tensorflow.org/get_started/datasets_quickstart#reading_a_csv_file

It is also possible to use imperative Python functions (see "Applying arbitrary Python logic with tf.py_func()" at the first link), though this is only recommended if there's no other option.

So, basically, unless you're using the `tf.py_fun()` mechanism, you can't expect any normal Python operations that depend on TF tensors or operations, to work as intended. They can, however, be used for looping constructs to set up interrelated TF ops.

UPDATE:

Here's a schematic example:

```
## For a simple example, I have four files <index>_<channel>_File.txt
## so, 1_1_File.txt, 1_2_File.txt

import tensorflow as tf

def input_parser(filename):
   filesWithChannels = []

   for i in range(1,3):
       channel_data =  tf.read_file(filename+'_'+str(i)+'_File.txt')

       ## Uncomment the two lines below to add csv parsing.
       # channel_data = tf.sparse_tensor_to_dense(tf.string_split([channel_data],'\n'), default_value='')
       # channel_data = tf.decode_csv(channel_data, record_defaults=[[1.],[1.]])

       filesWithChannels.append(channel_data)

   return tf.convert_to_tensor(filesWithChannels)


train_imgs = tf.constant(["1","2"]) # e.g.
tr_data = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(train_imgs)
tr_data = tr_data.map(input_parser)

iterator = tr_data.make_one_shot_iterator()
next_element = iterator.get_next()

with tf.Session() as sess:
    for i in range(2) :
        out = sess.run(next_element)
        print(out)
```

UPDATE UPDATE (add csv):

```
## For a simple example, I have four files <index>_<channel>_File.txt
## so, 1_1_File.txt, 1_2_File.txt

import tensorflow as tf

with tf.device('/cpu:0'):
    def input_parser(filename):
       filesWithChannels = []

       for i in range(1,3):
             channel_data = (tf.data.TextLineDataset(filename+'_'+str(i)+'_File.txt')
                               .map(lambda line: tf.decode_csv(line, record_defaults=[[1.],[1.]])))

             filesWithChannels.append(channel_data)

       return tf.data.Dataset.zip(tuple(filesWithChannels))

train_imgs = tf.constant(["1","2"]) # e.g.
tr_data = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(train_imgs)
tr_data = tr_data.flat_map(input_parser)

iterator = tr_data.make_one_shot_iterator()
next_element = iterator.get_next()
next_tensor_element = tf.convert_to_tensor(next_element)

with tf.Session() as sess:
    for i in range(2) :
        out = sess.run(next_tensor_element)
        print(out)
```

Have a look at [tf.decode_csv](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/decode_csv) for details on how to set the field delimiter and specify columns numbers and defaults using `column_defaults`.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying things up. I already browsed that link several times, and I am still unsure what functions replace the 5 lines in my `input_parser` function. Could you give some hint as to which functions should replace it so it conforms to the TF declarative model?

Comment: @olamundo- see my update above.  This was admittedly trickier that I'd appreciated from the details in the links provided.

Comment: Thank you so very much! I can't say that the lack of documentation at this stage is making me very optimistic regarding the next steps :)

Comment: Actually the above code doesn't really parse the CSV, does it? i.e., it doesn't create a matrix from each one of the files. That's the part that was hard to me, parsing the CSV into a matrix using the declarative model.

Comment: Indeed- TF feels a bit like the wild west, changing quickly and the docs are awfully thin.  I think some of the trickiness is related to its flexibility... there's often no one way that fits every kind of ML problem.  But the conceptual disorientation can be pretty severe.

Comment: To elaborate on my last question, I guess my csv is not typical in the sense that it doesn't represent a table of entries per row, but rather a 2D matrix (a channel for a multi-channeled 2D image). So my question is, how to parse that into a matrix.

Comment: OK, so I added an additional example.  It's essentially constructing your dataset by combining individual datasets on individual files streaming through tf.decode_csv.  A simpler solution might be to use my original example and do tf.read_data -> tf.split on linebreaks -> tf.decode_csv and construct complete csv parsed tensors.  I was having trouble making that work.

Comment: *tf.split -> tf.string_split

Comment: You are a saint! Wish I could upvote this 100 times.

Comment: Happy to help, @olamundo.  I've added (commented-out) csv parsing to the original "Update" example, which, I think is easier to understand than the latter.  And do "accept" if this addresses your question :-).

Comment: Sorry! Was sure I accepted immediately when you answered!